# How to use Deriv with a matrix structure in r

Tags: r, derivative

I am computing a partial derivative using `Deriv` for the function below but I keep getting errors probably because Deriv can not understand the symbols I am using within my defined function.

[image]

m1 and m2 have 3 elements each or you would think of it as a matrix of 3 columns and 2 rows where each row represents each `m_i`

I have defined the function `f` in r as:

```
f <- function(m,q){
  structure(vapply(seq(3), function(j) 
    12 * log(sum(vapply(seq(2), function(i) exp(m[i,j]) * q[i], double(1))) + q[3]), 
    double(1)), dim=c(1,3))
}
```

The i's and j's are only useful because I am planning to broaden the function. Could there be a way I would define this function so that I am able to compute the `f1` as defined above?

```
f1 = Deriv(f, "m[i, ]")
```

Or could there be any other package that could handle such a problem?